# Parsing request body prohibits request signature verification

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, slack-api, serverless-framework, ngrok

I'm trying to build a serverless Slackbot using Lambda function. I end up with an error while verifying the Request URL through the Slack event API. `@slack/events-api` is the dependency that I'm using to capture the slack events.

Here is my code.

```
const sls = require('serverless-http');
const { createEventAdapter } = require('@slack/events-api');
require('dotenv').config();

const { SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET } = process.env
const slackEvents = createEventAdapter( SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET || '' );


slackEvents.on('message', async event => {
  console.log('received!')
});


module.exports.server = sls(slackEvents.requestListener());
```

This is the error that I'm getting while verifing the request url

[image]

> Slack Request URL verification

[image]

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this exact issue, and took a look into [http-handler.js](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-events-api/blob/f0b4d3570def715900ce47588d768c2c4ffccb52/src/http-handler.js#L152-L174) in `node-slack-events`.

All we have to do is store the raw request body as `rawBody` before `serverless-http` parses it.

`serverless-http` lets you [transform the request](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-http/blob/master/docs/ADVANCED.md#transformations), before it is sent to the app—great opportunity for a fix:

```js
module.exports.handler = serverless(app, {
  request(request) {
    request.rawBody = request.body;
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to solve your problem exactly, but I do know what's causing it.

The library you're using, [`serverless-http`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-http) parses the JSON body sent by Slack. This causes an error to be thrown, because the [slack-api-sdk](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/blob/master/packages/events-api/src/http-handler.ts#L142) expects to parse the raw request body itself.

Could you try removing `serverless-http` and just respond to the API Gateway event?

Comment: I've removed it.
Still getting the same error with a different stack trace.

Comment: That's great! Could you share the stack trace and your new handler logic?

Comment: Hi Aaron, Here is my new [logic](https://gist.github.com/Prakhil-tp/f32268b70864fdb1eba092ac11527c92)  and the [stack_trace](https://i.paste.pics/79GB2.png).  Could you please look at it.

Comment: And this is the [CloudWatch_log](https://i.paste.pics/79HCP.png).